# RestKit: How to handle failure result with different mapping

Tags: restkit

I'm fetching a user object from a server. If the request succeeds I get:

```
{ user = {
        User = { id = 1; }
} }
```

On failure I get:

```
{ user = false; }
```

I have a mapping that works fine in the success case: `[mappingProvider setMapping:userMapping forKeyPath:@"user.User"];`

But in the failure case, I get the following exception: `'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFBoolean 0x1c58f78> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key User.'` I also tried setting `userMapping` as a relationship for keypath `User` on a mapping to generate an `NSDictionary` from the `user` keypath, no joy there either.

What is the correct way to deal with this? It seems like I need two different mappings for the `user` keypath, and to select which one based on whether on whether the object wants to be decoded to an NSBoolean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `RKDynamicObjectMapping`. Either of one of these two flavors should work for you:

```
- (void)setObjectMapping:(RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping whenValueOfKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath isEqualTo:(id)value;
```

or

```
+ (RKDynamicObjectMapping *)dynamicMappingUsingBlock:(void(^)(RKDynamicObjectMapping *dynamicMapping))block;
```

Comment: i gave it a try using `RKDynamicObjectMapping`, but couldn't figure out what type the `(id)value` expects (it kept on crashing). i think i rather need a function like `setObjectMapping:whenClassOfKeyPath:isEqualToClass:`

Answer (score 0):

The server is probably (and hopefully) returning an http error code such as 400 etc.. so probably Restkit is trying to map the response using the error mapping.

Perhaps what you need to do is dynamic object mapping as @Paul says..but applied to the error mapping. I here leave you a simple error mapping so you know what I'm talking about:

```
RKObjectMapping *errorMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKErrorMessage class]];
[errorMapping mapKeyPath:@"msg" toAttribute:@"errorMessage"];
[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] mappingProvider] setErrorMapping:errorMapping];
```